# Why I am getting 403 forbidden error with mockmvc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mocking

I am trying to mock itemService.deleteItem() method but getting a 403 status code, (I am using spring security, and for that, I have used @WithMockUser annotation)

Controller:
`

> @DeleteMapping("/deleteitem")
> @ApiOperation("Delete item from database")
> public ResponseEntity<ItemsModel> deleteItem(@RequestBody DeleteItemDto deleteItemDto) {
> return itemService.deleteItem(deleteItemDto);
>
> }

`

Service:

```
public ResponseEntity<ItemsModel> deleteItem(DeleteItemDto deleteItemDto)
{
 int itemId = deleteItemDto.getItemId();
Optional<ItemsModel> itemsModel  =  itemRepo.findById(itemId);
if(itemsModel.isPresent())
{
   try
   {
   itemRepo.delete(itemsModel.get());
   
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      logger.log(Level.INFO,"Exception while deleting item"+e);
      return new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

   }
   return ResponseEntity.ok(itemsModel.get());    
   }
else
{
   return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}

}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void testDeleteItem() throws Exception {
   Mockito.when(itemRepo.findById(ArgumentMatchers.any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(new ItemsModel()));
   ItemsModel itemsModel=mock(ItemsModel.class);
// itemsModel.setItemId(401);
   doNothing().when(itemRepo).delete(itemsModel);

   MvcResult mvcResult=mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.delete("/admin/deleteitem/").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andReturn();

assertEquals(200,mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus());
}
```

Error message:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = DELETE
      Request URI = /admin/deleteitem/
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@1fa35f7e, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT=SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tushar, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ADMIN]]]}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :200
Actual   :403
<Click to see difference>


    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.failNotEqual(AssertionUtils.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:150)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertEquals.assertEquals(AssertEquals.java:145)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals(Assertions.java:527)
```

Comment: Does your API expect authorization ? in form of header or something ? You may think of mocking it or passing it as well

Comment: Thank you for the response @Harsh, Yes I am using spring security for authorization. I have used the @WithMockUser(username = "tushar", password = "tushar", roles = "ADMIN") annotation but still I am getting a 403 status code.